# manipulating JavaScript AST without compromising source maps

Tags: javascript, abstract-syntax-tree, rollupjs

I've been playing with a Rollup plugin to abuse JSX for code generation (I'm aware of [Sweet.js macros](https://www.sweetjs.org); this is mostly an educational effort), but struggling to find guidance on AST manipulation. After some research, I have cobbled together an approach that sort of works, but seems problematic in various ways, so I wonder what the best practices are here.

Rollup provides an ESTree via Acorn to plugins, so it appears [estraverse](https://github.com/estools/estraverse) is the standard approach here. Let's say I just wanted to turn `<div>` into `"<div>"` (`rewriteNode` is generic AST stuff, the rest is Rollup-specific):

```
import escodegen from "escodegen"
import estraverse from "estraverse"

function rewriteNode(node, parent) {
    if(node.type !== "JSXElement") {
        return
    }

    const tagName = node.openingElement.name.name
    return {
        type: "Literal",
        value: `<${tagName}>`
    }
}

function transformModule(code, id) {
    if(!id.endsWith(".jsx")) { // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        return null
    }

    const ast = this.parse(code)
    ast = estraverse.replace(ast, {
        keys: {
            JSXElement: [] // ¯\_(ツ)_/¯
        },
        enter: rewriteNode
    })

    return {
        ast,
        code: escodegen.generate(ast)
    }
}

export default {
    name: "jsx-macros",
    transform: transformModule
}
```

There are several related issues here:

- Returning a plain `{ type, value }` object seems insufficient: Proper `Node` instances also contain `start` and `end` properties, among others. I assume these are required to generate proper source maps?
- Instead of using `estraverse.replace` and returning a new node, I might use [acorn-walk](https://github.com/acornjs/acorn/tree/master/acorn-walk) to traverse and remember the string positions and rewrite the `code` string afterwards. That seems like awkwardly reinventing the wheel though and would also mess with source maps?
- It appears [escodegen](https://github.com/estools/escodegen) doesn't actually support JSX at the moment, throwing `TypeError: this[type] is not a function`. Which is why I wonder...
- Why does Rollup require the plugin to return both `ast` and `code`; the latter seems redundant?

(Rollup is relevant here because it allows processing an entire module-dependency graph.)